# Function to get the news from files and post them on the homepage

Tags: php, file, function, include, indexing

I have to print those news on my homepage.
On the index.php file I setted include this file below, but nothing is returned... Where is the error?
The script get the news from files.
Then it set each news into a string.
Then the function creates a "standard" echo for each news
Then the news are printed.

But nothing is printed...

Thank you everybody!

```
<?php
if (file_exists("./public/ita/news/news.txt")) {
$getnews1 = "./public/ita/news/news.txt";
$news1 = file($getnews1); //file in to an array
}

if (file_exists("./public/ita/news/news2.txt")) {
$getnews2 = "./public/ita/news/news2.txt";
$news2 = file($getnews2); //file in to an array
}

if (file_exists("./public/ita/news/news3.txt")) {
$getnews3 = "./public/ita/news/news3.txt";
$news3 = file($getnews3); //file in to an array
}

if (file_exists("./public/ita/news/news4.txt")) {
$getnews4 = "./public/ita/news/news4.txt";
$news4 = file($getnews4); //file in to an array
}

if (file_exists("./public/ita/news/news5.txt")) {
$getnews5 = "./public/ita/news/news5.txt";
$news5 = file($getnews5); //file in to an array
}

function post_news()
    {
        echo '<div align="left" class="newstitle">';
        echo $news[0];
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div align="left" class="news">';
        echo '<p></p>';
        echo $news[1];
        echo $news[2];
        echo $news[3];
        echo $news[4];
        echo $news[5];
        echo $news[6];
        echo $news[7];
        echo $news[8];
        echo $news[9];
        echo $news[10];
        echo $news[11];
        echo '</div>';
    }

if($news1 != NULL) {
    $news = $news1;
    post_news();
}

if($news2 != NULL) {
    $news = $news2;
    post_news();
}

if($news3 != NULL) {
    $news = $news3;
    post_news();
}

?>
```

Comment: $news1 is not the same as $news[1] ;)

Comment: $news1 is the file news. $news[1] is the first row of that file... That's not my problem unfortunately

Comment: you should learn about scope of variables in PHP.. as well as variable names.. and types ! you got some way to go..

Comment: I was hinting towards a solution, indeed the names are different. $news is different outside of your function than inside.

Comment: @Perocat - If `$news1` is an array of the lines of a file, then you access the first line with `$news1[0]`... you never created an array called `$news`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots wrong here.

1 - **You're not creating a `$news` array**. Create a `$news` array at the top and populate it:

```
$news = array();
$news[0]=file(...)
```

2 - **`$news` isn't global** in any case, so the function can't see it. Either modify the function to allow you to pass in a variable:

```
function post_news($news){...
```

and then call it with

```
post_news($news);
```

Or make the news array global. You can do this by either creating `$news` as a global array (`$GLOBALS['news']=array()`) and then accessing it in the function from the global array, or by calling `global $news` in the beginning of your function.

3 - **Learn about `isset()`**. You try to just print out each news item `$news[0], etc` without checking that an element exists for that key. Try using a `foreach()` loop.

4 - Assuming that you property set the news items as an array, get variable scope correct, and use a foreach loop, **you then try to `echo` an array**... which you cannot do. Either change your `file()` calls to `file_get_contents()` or loop through each element of each news item and print the string.

### Overall, you need to learn more about scope, arrays, and loops.

Have a look at this code.. I've tried to explain what I'm doing at each step and why it's a better approach:

```
<?php
//Create an array with all the possible news items
$possible_files = array(
    "./public/ita/news/news.txt",
    "./public/ita/news/news2.txt",
    "./public/ita/news/news3.txt",
    "./public/ita/news/news4.txt",
    "./public/ita/news/news5.txt"
);

//Now loop through these files, check if they exist, and then pass the lines into your function
foreach($possible_files as $possible_file){
    if (file_exists($possible_file)){
         /*why create an array and then loop through it?
           Do everything here... grab the lines and then
           have it echeod out via post_news() in one step */
        $lines_of_news_items = file($possible_file);    
        //PASS this array into the function!
        post_news($lines_of_news_items); 
    }
}

function post_news($news_item_lines){
    //watch out for align='left'... it's an antiquated attribute
    echo '<div align="left" class="newstitle">';
    //print the first line here
    echo $news_item_lines[0]; 
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div align="left" class="news">';
    //btw, this <p></p> is bad practice... if you're trying to create space use css
    echo '<p></p>'; 
    //now loop though each line, starting with the second line ([1])
    for($i=1;$i<count($news_item_lines);$i++){ 
        echo $news_item_lines[$i];
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete explanation...
I'm "learning" php by myself since 1 month so I'm completely not practical with scope, arrays and loops. Now with your guide I've understand what you're doing.

I'm using CSS but <p></p> was the fastest way to create space. The div is aligned to left because is on a table aligned on the center.

Comment: @Perocat, normally I'd recommend asking a separate question, but in this case, just modify your stylesheet: `.newstitle {text-align:left; margin-bottom:12px;} .news {text-align:left;}`

Comment: Thank you again, I was able to do that... In fact is much better to have all on CSS... the HTML will be cleaner! You said me to learn more about scope, arrays, etc. is the php manual the best way to do that?
Sorry again about "lots wrong", but I'm really at the beginning!

Comment: @Perocat -  no worries... some of the concepts are a little tricky, but you'll get the hang of it. I'm not sure where to point you as far as tutorials. You might try [this](http://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/), but honestly a book is probably the best place to start.

Comment: I did now a form to create a new news.
When I "submit" the form, before the php create the new "news.txt" file I have to rename the old news so that news2 -> news3, news3 -> news4 etc.

What am I doing wrong here?

for($i=2;$i=5;$i++) { 
    rename('news{$i}.txt','news{$i++}.txt');
}

Comment: oof... you may want to change your approach for several reasons, including security, but also because this is what databases are built to do. Regardless, on an upload, you can first [loop through](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) the `/public/ita/news/` directory, check the names and modify each one. HOWEVER, you might want to consider just naming the newest one with the largest number and reading through them in reverse order? Regardless, this is an issue for another question (we try to avoid long discussions in the comments)

Comment: So you suggest me to use database for the news? Because I already use database for other things, such as charts data etc... I'll post another question!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your function: You are using `$news` there but you have not declared it a global variable, nor have you passed it to the function.

So `$news` is undefined in your function.

You should replace your function calls with `post_news($news);` and your function definition with `function post_news($news)` for it to work (global variables are bad...).

Comment: Can you please explain me better how to fix that? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you it works!!!
So this function is with global variables and is not good?
Global variables are not disabled by defaut for security reason in php.ini?

Comment: @Perocat No, I am not relying on global variables but passing the variable to the function.

Comment: If I would like to print from row 2 to the last row of the file how can I do that?
I'm now printing the title (row 0) with a class and then all other stuff (row 1 - row 11) with another class, but if possible I'd like to print from row 1  to last row instead of row 11...